# no error is produced while executing the do while statements

Tags: java

Why no output is produced in the following program.Can someone explain the logic of the program.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l=1;
        do while (l<1)
        System.out.print("l is" +l);
        while (l>1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no output generated, because your `do while()` treates the `while` as first statement of its body.

What you are doing is actually this:

```
do 
    while (l<1)
        System.out.print("l is" +l);
while (l>1);
```

Since this is correct syntax there is no error produced.

Answer (score -1):

You've actually created two loops.

The first one is here:

```
do while (l<1)
```

This is a do-while loop with no body and no statements, therefore it will do absolutely nothing.

The second loop is here:

```
while (l>1);
```

Since this loop also has no body, this loop will do absolutely nothing.

I believe that the format you are looking for is below:

```
int l=1;
do {
    System.out.print("l is" +l);
} while (l<1);
```

This is a single loop with a body that contains one statement (the `print()` call)